# Looping through a list so that it prints new list for every item containing factors of that item

Tags: python, list, for-loop

How can I modify the following code so that it prints separate lists containing the factors of items in a given list?

```
n = [3,4,5]
for i in n:
    print('Factors of ', i)
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        if i%j == 0:
           print(j)
```

Comment: What output do you expect? See [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a simple `factors` function and then do the loop

```
def factors(n):
    """Not the most optimal solution"""
    return [i for i in range(1, n+1) if not n % i]

n = [3, 4, 5]
for i in n:
    print(f'Factors of {i} = {factors(i)}')
```

outputs

```
Factors of 3 = [1, 3]
Factors of 4 = [1, 2, 4]
Factors of 5 = [1, 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
n = [3,4,5]
for i in n:
    print('Factors of ', i)
    remaining = i
    while remaining > 1 :
        for j in range(2,remaining+1):
            if remaining%j == 0:
               print(j)
           remaining /= j
```

Result:

```
('Factors of ', 3)
3
('Factors of ', 4)
2
2
('Factors of ', 5)
5
>>>
```

Which works coincidentally like the Linux command `factor` :

```
$ factor 3 4 5
3: 3
4: 2 2
5: 5
```

Answer (score -1):

I have refactored your code a little bit to make it more readable and easy to understand:

```
n = [3, 4, 5]

def get_factors(num):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            result.append(i)
    return result

print([get_factors(elem) for elem in n])
```

Let me know if this answers your question?